# SvgConverter bug

Tags: svg, itext7

I am using SvgConverter to add a simple SVG to a PDF. I receive the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.styledxmlparser.exceptions.StyledXMLParserException: The passed value (@null) is not a number
```

Here is the SVG content itself:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Disclaimer: I am an employee at iText Software

Your SVG file does not contain a `width` and `height` attribute in its root element, nor a `viewbox`. <strike>That is (technically) not compliant with the SVG specification.</strike>

However, this kind of declaration of the `svg` element is relatively common in the wild, so we have already fixed the issue and it will be supported in the upcoming release of iText Core, which is due in a few weeks (for future reference: Oct 2018).

Edit: if you want to test sooner, then you can build iText from source (https://github.com/itext/itext7) because the fix has been in the `develop` branch for a few weeks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with an SVG that has neither a width, nor height nor viewBox. Which part of the SVG specification do you think forbids this?

Comment: Ok I should have been more nuanced - and I won't pretend I know better than you :-) Absence of width and height implies that both values are `100%`, but `100%` of what ? A relative value makes sense for embedded SVGs, but for outermost SVG documents, you need at least some constraints.

Comment: 100% of the container, the browser content window if it's a browser. Actually 100% is not the value for embedded SVGs as the rules are different for replaced content.

Comment: Maybe the better nuance is: How to define what 100% is when converting to a PDF Object/iText image? As long as the image isn't added to any parent, the width of its parent container is unknown. PDF and HTML, while both roughly serve the same purpose, on a technical level don't behave the same and trying to map certain concepts onto the other isn't going to happen. Initially we made the design choice to not accept these SVGs, but we quickly came back to that decision as blagae mentions ;)

disclaimer: iText employee as well